# Simplifying Long Switch Statements

Tags: javascript

I need to brush up on my javascript because it is my weakest language, so I thought "Hey lets make a simple 'translating' program to test my skills". Well I was able to make it translate one way so far(I havent worked on untranslating the stuff people input), but anyway the way it does it is by a series of many cases inside a switch. Im wondering if there is anyway I can simplify the code instead of having a million switch cases. Thanks here is my code.

```
function main() {
            var get = prompt("Enter what you would like to encode!","At the current time decoding is still a WIP").toLowerCase();
            var ina = [...get];
            for(i = 0; i < ina.length; i++) {
                switch(ina[i]) {
                case "a":
                    ina[i] = "z";
                    break;
                case "b":
                    ina[i] = "y";
                    break;
                case "c":
                    ina[i] = "x";
                    break;
                case "d":
                    ina[i] = "w";
                    break;
                case "e":
                    ina[i] = "v";
                    break;
                case "f":
                    ina[i] = "u";
                    break;
                case "g":
                    ina[i] = "t";
                    break;
                case "h":
                    ina[i] = "s";
                    break;
                case "i":
                    ina[i] = "r";
                    break;
                case "j":
                    ina[i] = "q";
                    break;
                case "k":
                    ina[i] = "p";
                    break;
                case "l":
                    ina[i] = "o";
                    break;
                case "m":
                    ina[i] = "n";
                    break;
                case "n":
                    ina[i] = "m";
                    break;
                case "o":
                    ina[i] = "l";
                    break;
                case "p":
                    ina[i] = "k";
                    break;
                case "q":
                    ina[i] = "j";
                    break;
                case "r":
                    ina[i] = "i";
                    break;
                case "s":
                    ina[i] = "h";
                    break;
                case "t":
                    ina[i] = "g";
                    break;
                case "u":
                    ina[i] = "f";
                    break;
                case "v":
                    ina[i] = "e";
                    break;
                case "w":
                    ina[i] = "d";
                    break;
                case "x":
                    ina[i] = "c";
                    break;
                case "y":
                    ina[i] = "b";
                    break;
                case "z":
                    ina[i] = "a";
                    break;
                default:
                    ina[i] = ina[i]
                    };
                };
                var outa = ina.join("");
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = outa;

            };
```

Comment: That depends, is there consistency? For instance, it seems like you're translating to the same alphabet backwards, which would probably be a lot easier to do with just an array of characters and using the length etc. but for other patterns, that might not work, so do you want something for this pattern only, or some easier way to write a switch in general *(which there really are none)*.

Comment: If you have working code that you'd like to improve, you can also ask on http://codereview.stackexchange.com. They'll help you improve all aspects of your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an object with properties like

```
{
    a: 'z',
    b: 'y',
    c: 'x',
    // ...
    z: 'a'
}
```

Usage with the default value of `ina[i]`.

```
ina[i] = object[ina[i]] || ina[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a couple string variables to map the letters.

```
function translateLetter(input) {
    const untranslated = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    const translated   = "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba";

    var i = untranslated.indexOf(input);
    return translated[i];
}
```

Comment: You'd want to make sure you handled the case where the input isn't in `untranslated`; as is, you'll return `undefined` for all those. This also involves linear scans for every character; admittedly it likely JITs to something like a `memchr` call which is fairly fast, but you could compute the index directly just as easily without scanning.

Comment: Compute v. Scanning-- a classic case of performance v. extensibility.  Well at least I don't have it calling a service.

Answer (score 1):

The `switch` you're using has logic that can be implemented directly without needing the `switch` at all via simple math (I believe most modern JS interpreters should JIT away the actual method calls if this is a hot loop, so the cost there should be trivial):

```
var get = prompt("Enter what you would like to encode!","At the current time decoding is still a WIP").toLowerCase();
var ina = [...get];
for(i = 0; i < get.length; i++) {
    var code = get.charCodeAt(i);
    if (97 <= code && code <= 122) {  // 'a' and 'z' ordinal values
        // Invert lowercase letters with simple math and convert back to character
        ina[i] = String.fromCharCode((122 + 97) - code);
    }
    // No need to handle non-lowercase/non-ASCII since ina initialized to match get
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do the math on the ASCII character codes:

```
function main() {
    var get = prompt("Enter what you would like to encode!","At the current time decoding is still a WIP").toLowerCase();
    var ina = [...get];

    for (i = 0; i < get.length; i++) {
        var charNum = get.charCodeAt(i) - 96;

        if (charNum > 0 && charNum < 27) {
            ina[i] = String.fromCharCode((27 - charNum) + 96);
        }
    };

    var outa = ina.join("");
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = outa;
};
```