# Why is this Javascript failing to find the right index?

Tags: javascript

I was testing my answer to another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39800833/simplifying-long-switch-statements/39800919#39800919) and came across this weird behavior, for the life of me I don't know what is up.

Code:

```js
function translateLetter(input) {
    const untranslated = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    const translated   = "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba";

    var i = untranslated.indexOf(input);
    console.log(i);
    return translated.substring(i,1);
}
console.log(translateLetter("a"));
console.log(translateLetter("b"));
console.log(translateLetter("c"));
```

Expected output:

```
0
z
1
y
2
x
```

Actual output:

```
0
z
1
          <--- WTH?
2
y         <--- WTF?
```

[Code on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kLxsase3/)

Comment: You mean `substr` instead of `substring`. Or just use `[i]` instead.

Comment: Ugh.  Must be Friday.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

If speed is important, I'd use an object to do your lookup.
eg.

```
var translateLetter= {a:'z',b:'y'... etc }
```

and then you can simply do ->

```
console.log(translateLetter['a'])
```

Comment: Better than the original

Answer (score 0):

Use `.substr()` for a length. `.substring()` takes a position.

Answer (score 0):

The first empty space is a null because you have passed "b" in the function on which indexOf function returned 1 which is then set to variable "i" and i is then used in substring function and substring fuction return the value which is in the middle including the first and excluding the last index of the values given so substring got (1,1) and  1,1 are pointing the same index so it returned null.

same for the second.

substring(Begin index inclusive,last index exclusive);